# Dropbox: What happens when I delete shared files?

Tags: dropbox

In Dropbox on OSX, I have a local folder that I have shared with another Dropbox user, Bob.

Previously, I put some files in this folder, and Bob got them synced on his PC.

Just now, I ACCIDENTALLY put some other files in that folder, which I under no circumstances want Bob to see.

Realizing my mistake, I immediately removed them from this local folder; some of them had already uploaded, but not all.

I then promptly logged onto dropbox.com and removed Bob from this shared folder, just to be sure.

Question 1: If Bob's PC was turned off when I did this, is there any chance he will see the files?

Question 2: If Bob's PC was turned on when I did this, is there any chance he will see the files?

Answer (score 3):

When you put the files on the shared folder it automatically started syncing your files to Bob's computer, that is unless his computer was off-line.
When you deleted the files - the "delete" command also started to sync and was supposed to delete the files from his folder. If you had luck - all the files were deleted - but if not, the fact that you revoked his credentials from the folder might have left a few files (which didn't have enough time to sync and be deleted) there. I would delete all the files from this folder and return his credentials just to make sure that the "delete" command was synced as well.

Hope it helps.